# Loop through an array of DIvs and display their innerHTML as H Tags?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

For each block of text like this:

```
<div class="articles-slider">
<div class="slick-slide"><div class="user-title">danny<div>...more DIVs....<ul class="socials">.... 
</ul><div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div class="user-title">jane<div>...more DIVs....<ul class="socials">.... 
</ul><div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div class="user-title">tom<div>...more DIVs....<ul class="socials">.... 
</ul><div>
<div>
```

1. Loop through-the class"user-title" array and extract their inner html.

   ```
   var theNames = [];
   jQuery('.user-title').each(function () {
       theNames.push(this.innerHTML);
   });
   ```
2. Add an empty H4 TAG before UL class="socials".

   ```
   var theNames = [];
   jQuery(".socials").prepend('<H4 class="sr-only the_title"></H4>');
   jQuery('.user-title').each(function () {
       theNames.push(this.innerHTML);
   });
   ```

-ASKING FOR HELP-

3. Add the names.innerhtml to the H4 tags respectively.

   ```
   var theNames = [];
   var theNamesText = [];
   jQuery(".socials").prepend('<H4 class="sr-only the_title"></H4>');
   jQuery('.user-title').each(function () {    
       theNames.push(this.innerHTML);
   });
   ```

Comment: Hello, I am not sure what you try to achieve but below can help you:               
     $('.user-title').each(function () {   
  
    $(this).find( "ul" ).prepend('<H4 class="sr-only the_title">'+ $(this).text()  +'</H4>');
    
     });

  });

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're over complicating the problem.  There is no need to store the titles.  Based on your code you should be able find a container element that is a parent of the elements you wish to work with (`$container`).  Then find the elements you need to work with (`$userTitle` and `$socials`) and if they exist add your `H4` with a title.

```js
$('slick-slide').each(function() {
  var $container = $(this);
  var $userTitle = $container.find('.user-title');
  var $socials = $container.find('.socials');
  if ($userTitle.length == 1 && $socials.length == 1) {
    $socials.prepend('<H4 class="sr-only the_title">' $userTitle.innerHtml '</H4>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you altaf-khokhar and erik-philips:)

that works!

```
$('.slick-slide').each(function() {
  var $container = $(this);
  var $userTitle = $container.find('.user-title');
  var $socials = $container.find('.socials');
  if ($userTitle.length == 1 && $socials.length == 1) {
  $socials.prepend('<H4 class="sr-only the_title">' + $userTitle.text() + '</H4>');
   }
});
```